# How to replace slashes

Tags: java

I want to replace a single slash with double slashes in a path, but leave double slashes unaffected.
I tried the following:

```
string oldPath = "\\new\new1\new2\";
string newPath = old.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

My expected result is that `newPath` is as follows:

```
"\\new\\new1\\new2\\"
```

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: please show actual runnable code, in particular for your input string. *If* the string actually contains `\n` then there is no ``\`` to replace.

Comment: `\n` is a new line character. So your string is like \newNEW LINEew1NEW LINEew2

Comment: There is no error iam getting,it is not replacing with slashes

Comment: Please read [mcve]. Use **correct** java code, and tell us what you expect.

Comment: `String.replace` when called with 2 `String(s)` performs simple string replacement. Its not a regex and you dont need to escape.
If all you are trying to do is replace `\` with `\\` , `old.replace("\","\\")` will work. But it will also replace the double slashes. What you need is a regex and not a simple string replace.

Comment: I need want output as : \\new\\new1\\new2\\

Comment: Use : 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

for regex.

Comment: Update your question instead of putting more info into comments please!

Comment: I made an edit, although we still don't know what he actually gets.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `\n` is interpreted as a new line. Escape one more time.

Anyways better, use `java.nio.file.Path` instead of `String` to work with files and direcory paths. Also, use `System.getProperty("file.separator")` to work with the file separator `\` \ `/`.

On a unix based system, path separator is `/`:

```
/**
 * Succeeds on Unix-based systems. On Windows, replace test Path and expected Path file separators
 * with backslash(es).
 */
@Test
public void test() {
    final Path oldPath = Paths.get("//new/new1/new2");
    final String newPath = oldPath.toString().replace(System.getProperty("file.separator"),
            System.getProperty("file.separator") + System.getProperty("file.separator"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.separator"));
    System.out.println(newPath);
    assertEquals("//new//new1//new2", newPath);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. The only thing is that your `newPath` will be `////new//new1//new2`.

Comment: I think not, run the test case ;)

Comment: I did before I wrote the comment. Not as a test, but `newPath` is printed in console as `\\\\new\\new1\\new2`.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe you are on Windows? For me the test case succeeds, and the output is
`/`
`//new//new1//new2`

Comment: Yes, Windows here. I'm surprised it's even trying to replace, because file separator is printed as `\ ` and there is no such sign in `oldPath`... Some strange translations are done behind the scene.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `oldPath` is not a valid string in Java. It ends with `\` which is a special character and it must be followed by something. Let's assume it should be `\\` at the end.

Besides this, as @Jens mentioned in comments, `\n` is a new line sign, so java understands your string as `\new(new_line)ew1(new_line)ew2\`.

Now, if you want your result to be **displayed** as `\\new\\new1\\new2\\` you need to use this

```
String newPath = old.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("\n", "\\\\n");
```

Notice that the order of `replace` methods is important in that case.